# Using a Secure CMS to output static content

Tags: security, php, cms

I'm looking specifically for CMS's that work by outputting static HTML.

Content management systems are in regular based on scripting languages and databases, like PHP and MySQL. This has some drawbacks: It requires to install, administer and maintain such systems on a web server, which is overkill for small and medium sized websites.

But most important: It implies vulnerabilities to hacker attacks. As we operate a high security site, I need to find a CMS that doesn't rely on traditional databases or PHP so that security can be tighter.

One example I found, for instance, used a C++ Compiler to output static HTML.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many: [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), [Octopress](http://octopress.org/), [Hyde](http://hyde.github.io/), [nanoblogger](http://nanoblogger.sourceforge.net/), [Pelican](http://www.getpelican.com/), etc. Which one you use depends on which languages you prefer, which templating systems you prefer, etc. So, try a few out and see what you like most.

Comment: I'll add my own in the comments since I don't want it to be the focus: [m4-bloggery](https://repos.invergo.net/fossil/m4-bloggery/index) (only requires M4 and Make!)

Answer (score -1):

I am really happy with Chronicle on Linux http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/chronicle/

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your answer appears very basic. Instead of blindly linking something with little explanation, I would include some information explaining why you would choose Chronicle to solve OP's issue. We like detailed answers here. Please see our [help center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for information on writing good answers.